# C++ Pointer addition being multiplied

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am working on packet code, and need to move a pointer by X bytes. When I tell the pointer `pointer = pointer + X;` then proceed to print the pointer via to_string or cout, X*2 has been added to the pointer. I have tried this with multiple values, both constant and variable. I have verified the pointer's value before the operation. The only thing I can think when this happens is that the 3 is being bit-shifted somewhere. Any ideas?

Sample code:

```
cout << "Before: " << pointer << "\n";
pointer = pointer + 3;
cout << "After: " << pointer << "\n";
```

Output:

```
Before: 0x7ffff4604e93
After: 0x7ffff4604e99
```

My includes:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdarg>
```

Thank you,

Mike

Comment: What is the type of your pointer? It makes a difference.

Comment: it's a custom defined struct, which is pragma packed

Comment: Okay, what is `sizeof(my_struct)` ?

Comment: it prints out 2, which is correct, it is 2 bytes

Comment: It might help to know that `*(pointer + 3)` is equal to `pointer[3]`.

Comment: That's your reason. Pointer arithmetic keeps in mind the size of what you're pointing at, so `p + 3` is actually `p + 3 * sizeof(*p)`.

Comment: I may see where you are leading, when I add 1 to my pointer, it thinks I want to reference the next struct, so it adds 2?

Comment: To move a pointer by `n` bytes you need to cast it to a `char *` or a `void *` (they have the same alignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pointer = pointer + X;` does not move the pointer by `X` bytes, it moves it by `X * sizeof(*pointer)` bytes. In this case, if the size of your `struct` is 2 bytes, `pointer = pointer + 3` should move it 6 bytes, which it has.

Answer (score 4):

When you use

```
pointer = pointer + 3;
```

The numerical difference between the value of `pointer` before and after is `3*sizeof(*pointer)`.

In your case, since `sizeof(*pointer)` is `2`, you see a difference of 6. Everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer addition in C and C++ always multiplies what you add by the size of what the pointer points to. So if `p` is a pointer to `int`, `p+1` is a pointer to the next `int`, not the next byte. If you want to access pointers by exact bytes, you'll have to make sure they are pointers to `char` or other 1-byte type. `((char*)p)+1` always points to the byte after `p`, regardless of its type.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to increment your pointer by 1 byte, you could create another pointer and increment that to get the address, then assign the address of it into the existing pointer:

```
char *newPointer = (char *)pointer;
newPointer = newPointer + 1;
```

Then you could assign the value back to `pointer` by:

```
pointer = &newPointer;
```

Be careful though like everyone else said as you won't be where you think you are in your struct anymore.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to shorten that, I'm just dusting off all the cobwebs...